# Can a map be added to a report generated through ExportReport using Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, pdf

I am currently able to generate a PDF report using arcpy's ExportReport that contains attribute information for records within an attribute table, but is there a way to add a map to that report, as another page, using python? I can't seem to find an documentation on this.

Comment: Yes, there are ArcPy functions to open a PDF and append pages from another PDF into it.

Comment: Excellent! Feel free to self-answer with a few sentences.  It will help you build reputation and unlock site functionality.